# ReactNative Expo Preloading & Caching Images

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I'm new to react-native im trying to preload 10 images at the start of the app I followed expo documentation but

I want to cache images from an external file but it gives me an error [Un Handeled Promise Rejection]

here is my entries.js

```
export const ENTRIES1 = [
    {
        title: 'Makeup Artists',
        illustration: require('../assets/img/makeup.png')
    },
    {
        title: 'Photographers',
        illustration: require('../assets/img/Photographers.png')
    },
    {
        title: 'Wedding Planners',
        illustration: require('../assets/img/weddingPlanner.jpg')
    },
    {
        title: 'Wedding Halls',
        illustration: require('../assets/img/wedding-Hall.png')
    },
    {
        title: 'Laser & Beauty Centers',
        illustration: require('../assets/img/laser.png')
    },
]
```

loadingScreen.js

```
      async componentDidMount() { //Preload Fonts
    await Asset.loadAsync(ENTRIES1.illustration),
    await Font.loadAsync({
        'Roboto': require('../../node_modules/native-base/Fonts/Roboto.ttf'),
        'Roboto_medium': require('../../node_modules/native-base/Fonts/Roboto_medium.ttf'),
      ...Ionicons.font,
    });
    this.checkIfLoggedIn();
  }
```

what am i doing wrong ? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try this :)

```
function cacheImages(images) {
  return images.map(image => {
    if (typeof image.illustration === 'string') {
      return Image.prefetch(image.illustration);
    } else {
      return Asset.fromModule(image.illustration).downloadAsync();
    }
  });
}

 async componentDidMount() { 


    await Asset.cacheImages(ENTRIES1),
    await Font.loadAsync({
        'Roboto': require('../../node_modules/native-base/Fonts/Roboto.ttf'),
        'Roboto_medium': require('../../node_modules/native-base/Fonts/Roboto_medium.ttf'),
      ...Ionicons.font,
    });
    this.checkIfLoggedIn();
  }
```

Comment: Local images url are correct im using them on the homescreen
but i want to preload them when the app starts before the user get to homescreen

Comment: thanks for your answer i tried it but i got 
`[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: _expoAsset.Asset.cacheImages is not a function. (In '_expoAsset.Asset.cacheImages(_entries.ENTRIES1)', '_expoAsset.Asset.cacheImages' is undefined)]`

Comment: You imported import { Asset } from 'expo-asset'; ?

Comment: Sure i did import it